# R-tree Range Query and Nearest Neighbor Search in Python

Tags: python-3.x, spatial-index, r-tree, range-query

where can I find an efficient implementation of R-tree and the range query and neighbor searching especially in Python?

Want to understand how these queries work using the code.(i am a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

You won't find an *efficient* version in (pure) Python.

Python is fairly expensive at working with complex data structures like the R-tree. For *efficiency* reasons, these are better implemented in Cython or even pure C, and only used from within Python. You can easily find some libraries for this with DuckDuckGo.

Comment: Can you share some link for this "Python is fairly expensive at working with complex data structures like the R-tree" or any reasons?

Comment: Interpreted code vs. compiled code. That is why Cython is used for, e.g., k-d-trees in sklearn. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython